# How to merge multiple CSV files into one file while keeping one column fixed?

Tags: python, csv

I have multiple .CSV files where the 1st column is similar for all the files. I want to create a single CSV file where all the 2nd columns from the csv files are merged vertically.

example: data_001.csv

|  |  |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 6.9 |
| 2 | 7.8 |
| 3 | 8.0 |

data_002.csv

|  |  |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 0.9 |
| 2 | 1.2 |
| 3 | 3.4 |

expected file:

|  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 6.9 | 0.9 |
| 2 | 7.8 | 1.2 |
| 3 | 8.0 | 3.4 |

I am just staring to learn programming and I am not very good at it! I have almost 100+ csv files with 1000+ rows so doing it manually isn't an option either. So any kind of help/suggestion will be much appreciated (including suggested reading materials/courses on data analysis.

Comment: Are you sure for the expected output? `1 6.9 0.9 2 *2* 7.8 1.2 3 8.0 3.4`

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow! Can you please elaborate more on column part? Your example values belong to second column, right?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. However, SO is not a general online help site. It is [off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) to ask for *any kind of help/suggestion* or *suggested reading materials/courses*. Please [research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1422451) on your own, pick a *specific* method, and then ask a *specific* question regarding your earnest attempt.